# Antlr4 Parse Tree Hierarchy from Context

Tags: c#, parsing, tree, listener, antlr4

Is there a way to get the Parent node information from the context input of the current node in the Listener?  I want to know where I am in the global hierarchy of the parse tree to make decisions about how certain nodes are processed.  I can implement a visited node stack but I believe the information should already be available somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can access the `Parent` property of the context node.